# How to find package that declares a managed maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

While upgrading dependencies in a project I ran across this issue:

```
[INFO] --- dependency-management-maven-plugin:0.11:analyze (basepom.default) @ svc-foo ---
[ERROR] Version mismatch for org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar, managed version 4.5.0 does not match project version 4.9.1
```

My question is: **How do I find out which package or artifact declares that liquibase-core is a managed dependency and should be at version 4.5.0?**

- Firstly, I know how to solve the issue (by overwriting the managed dependency in my own pom). That is not the question.
- Liquibase is not declared as managed dependency in our base pom or anywhere in the direct inheritance chain.
- `mvn dependency:tree` does not show it, as liquibase is not included as actual dependency anywhere else but in my own pom. But it is seemingly declared as managed with version 4.5.0 *somewhere*.
- I tried all maven goals/command I could find. I read the maven docs. I searched here on stackoverflow. What did I overlook?

Comment: Usually this comes from BOMs in dependencyManagement (`<scope>import</scope>`)

Comment: Sure, e.g. my parent pom imports spring boot and spring cloud which have further imports. Other dependencies I'm using might do the same. I was hoping to find a mysterious `mvn` command that can output some information guiding me to who declares what.

Comment: Often the IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ,...) give you information if you hover over a dependency.